# what does this guy mean by "Pulling on my flameproof underwear"?

Tags: meaning

There is a guy who said something strange to me https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24137/is-the-way-an-os-schedule-threads-related-to-parallel-computing#comment48182_24137

> Pulling on my flameproof underwear

What did he mean by that? thanks.

Btw, what is the purpose of making  underwear flameproof?

Comment: He is indicating that he expects to be 'flamed' (addressed in highly critical language) for what he has said. Flameproof underwear is valued by firefighters.

Comment: thanks. can you rephrase "addressed in highly critical language" so that I can understand what you mean better? btw, what is the purpose of making underwear flameproof in reality?

Answer (score 6):

The commenter is making a joke indicating that he expects to be ‘flamed’:

> **Flaming** is a hostile and insulting interaction between Internet users, often involving the use of profanity.
>
> Flaming usually occurs in the social context of an Internet forum, Internet Relay Chat (IRC), Usenet, by e-mail, game servers such as Xbox Live or PlayStation Network, and on video-sharing websites. It is frequently the result of the discussion of heated real-world issues such as politics, religion, and philosophy, or of issues that polarize sub-populations, but can also be provoked by seemingly trivial differences.
>
> Deliberate flaming, as opposed to flaming as a result of emotional discussions, is carried out by individuals known as flamers, who are specifically motivated to incite flaming. These users specialize in flaming and target specific aspects of a controversial conversation. Some websites even cater to flamers and trolls, by allowing them a free environment, such as Flame-Wars forum.
>     —Wikipedia, s.v. [Flaming (Internet)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flaming_(Internet))

Although the commenter is joking, there really is such a thing as flameproof—or at least flame-resistant—underwear. It is worn by firefighters, racecar drives, and others whose work brings a risk of having their clothing catch on fire, as it prevents or delays flame coming in actual contact with the flesh it covers. [Here](http://www.jjcraceandrally.com/race/racewear) and [here](http://www.hdth.com/fire-underwear/) are websites where flameproof underwear is sold.